# What is the difference between Sentence Encodings and Contextualized Word Embeddings?

Tags: nlp, word-embedding, elmo, bert-language-model

I have seen both terms used while reading papers about BERT and ELMo so I wonder if there is a difference between them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- A **contextualized word embeding** is a vector representing a word in a special context. The *traditional word embeddings* such as Word2Vec and GloVe generate one vector for each word, whereas a contextualized word embedding generates a vector for a word depending on the context. Consider the sentences `The duck is swimming`and `You shall duck when someone shoots at you`. With traditional word embeddings, the word vector for `duck`would be the same in both sentences, whereas it should be a different one in the contextualized case.
- While word embeddings encode words into a vector representation, there is also the question on how to represent a whole sentence in a way a computer can easily work with. These **sentence encodings** can embedd a whole sentence as one vector , doc2vec for example which generate a vector for a sentence. But also BERT generates a representation for the whole sentence, the [CLS]-token.

So in short, a conextualized word embedding represents a word in a context, whereas a sentence encoding represents a whole sentence.